# Bulk import select element options of a Webform from CSV

Tags: 8, webforms, importing-exporting

I am using the Webform 8.x-5.0-beta16 module in Drupal 8.

I added a select field in which I would like to set around 250 options.

Is there a way to easily import these options from a CSV?

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to enter the values editing the webform via Source(YAML).

The CSV values can be easily processed into a format such as " 'label': 'value' ".
Then when editing YAML source it's just a list you can Copy & Paste.

For the record, it would end up looking like this (and so on):

```
select_field:
 '#type': select
 '#title': 'Title'
 '#options':
   'label1': 'value1'
   'label2': 'value2'
```

Comment: In Drupal 9 (probably in 8 + 10 as well) you can edit the YAML directly in the admin: look for Source when creating your webforms options.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `hook_webform_options_alter()` or `hook_webform_options_WEBFORM_OPTIONS_ID_alter()` to dynamically populate options.

See https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/blob/HEAD/webform.api.php#L108 for more info.